# PostgreSQL & ActiveRecord - slow query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I run simple query:

```
History.where(channel_id: 1).order('histories.id DESC').first
```

Result:

```
History Load (808.8ms)  SELECT  "histories".* FROM "histories" WHERE "histories"."channel_id" = 1  ORDER BY histories.id DESC LIMIT 1  [["channel_id", 1]]
```

**808.8ms** for 1 of 7 records with channel_id = 1. Total histories count is 2,110,443.

If I select all histories for channel_id = 1:

```
History.where(channel_id: 1)

History Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "histories".* FROM "histories" WHERE "histories"."channel_id" = 1  [["channel_id", 1]]
```

It took only 0.5ms

And if we try to take one record with help of ruby Array:

```
History.where(channel_id: 1).order('histories.id DESC').to_a.first

History Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "histories".* FROM "histories" WHERE "histories"."channel_id" = 1  ORDER BY id DESC  [["channel_id", 1]]
```

Where I should find the problem?

PS: I already have an index on channel_id field.

UPD:

```
History.where(channel_id: 1).order('histories.id DESC').limit(1).explain
  History Load (848.9ms)  SELECT  "histories".* FROM "histories" WHERE "histories"."channel_id" = 1  ORDER BY histories.id DESC LIMIT 1  [["channel_id", 1]]
 => EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "histories".* FROM "histories" WHERE "histories"."channel_id" = 1  ORDER BY histories.id DESC LIMIT 1 [["channel_id", 1]]
                                              QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..13.52 rows=1 width=42)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using histories_pkey on histories  (cost=0.43..76590.07 rows=5849 width=42)
         Filter: (channel_id = 1)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Generally, a `channel_id, id` compound index should help. If your use case is special, i.e. you will only need the channel `1`, you could set up a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html).

Comment: @pozs thank you, solved by compound index `channel_id, id`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways PostgreSQL can handle your query (with the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses):

- It can scan the table and order the found tuples, then limit your result. PostgreSQL will choose this plan if he thinks your table has a really low number of tuples, or if he thinks the index will be of no use;
- It can use the index.

It seems that PostgreSQL did choose the first option, which can occur for only two reasons in my humble opinion:

- Your table statistics are not accurate. I recommend you VACUUM your table and try again this query
- The channel_id values are unevenly distributed (for example almost all of the tuples have channel_id=2), which is why PostgreSQL thinks that the index is of no use. Here I recommend the use of a partial index.